# Local Storage not supporting in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7

Currently I am using local storage to save an array that i get in master page and i want to use that same array in other pages. But it turns out that local storage is not supported in ie7 and my application needs to support IE7.

Is there any way I can do it without local storage ?

In masterpage :

```
exec cgi="GetOptions"

// This CGI returns an array which looks something like this
 var opts = new Array("0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
 "1", "0", "0", "1");

localStorage.setItem("opts", JSON.stringify(opts));
```

In Content Page:

```
var opts = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("opts") );
```

Any help would be appreciated.. Thanks in advance

Comment: use cookies as a backup to localStorage, but note that it has less space to use.

Comment: IE9+ support html5, IE6/7/8 don't, so local storage are not supported

Comment: @flybird: "HTML5" is no one thing. IE8 supports local storage. IE7 and below do not.

Comment: @flybird, OP mentions they know it is not supported, they are asking for an alternative

Comment: My question is: Really? You really have to support IE7? IE7's global market share is somewhere between [0.17%](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201306-201406) and [0.71%](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0) depending on who you ask. Of course, the only stats that really matter are the stats for **your** site/app, but... You might want to push back on whoever is telling you to support that *seriously*-outdated browser, get them to back up that requirement with data.

Comment: I agree.  You really ought to push back and find out why they want IE7 supported.  It would be pretty rare these days to have a good business case for it.  And, if you explain that the coding and testing will cost a lot more to make it work with IE7, that might make it even easier for them to understand why doing that extra work for some very tiny percentage of users probably doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can do it without local storage ?

The predecessor to local storage is cookies. But there's a reason we have local storage now: Cookies get sent to the server on every request (for images, for style sheets, etc.), have limited capacity, and are a real pain to use in JavaScript.

You can either use cookies directly, or search for "local storage polyfill" to find several options that provide `localStorage`-like solutions using cookies for underlying storage.

The size limit for cookies varies browser-to-browser; for IE7, it's 4096 bytes (to store both the key and value; you don't get to use all of that, some of it is used for overhead — storing expiration information, domain, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage uses a key:value system. But you can save more than one data in one key, using JSON.Stringify & JSON.parse.

For IE Localstorage u have to use a polyfill:-

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills